# How to include module as dependency and be able to build it to APK?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have following project structure:

```
main-project/
  modules/
    moduleA/
    moduleB/
```

`main-project` uses `moduleA` and `moduleB` as dependencies. Currently, these modules are library modules, however, I would like to be able to release them as standalone applications. Thus, I want to be able to release:

- `main-project` application (dependent on `moduleA` and `moduleB`)
- `moduleA` standalone application
- `moduleB` standalone application

There are more submodules than just `moduleA` and `moduleB`, so creating application modules for each of them is not an option (unless it is possible to automatize it by Gradle).

**Is there a possibility, using Gradle, to build `main-project` and its dependencies as separate APKs?**

**EDIT**

To better illustrate my problem, here is less abstract example of my project structure:

```
cats-dogs-browser/
  modules/
    cats-browser/
    dogs-browser/
```

I would like to release `cats-dogs-browser`, `cats-browser`, `dogs-browser` APKs. Both `cats-browser` and `dogs-browser` are able to work as standalone applications (they have own resources, activities etc.). Using flavours in `cats-dogs-browser` to include only one of modules is not an option as it contains a lot of logic that is not needed for `cats-browser` nor `dogs-browser` to work.

I know I can do it by providing application modules for `cats-browser` and `dogs-browser` (or using one such module with flavours), but in real project there is a lot more than 2 such modules so I am looking for better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to include another productFlavor with your module id?

Dunno if it's exactly what you want.

I can create 2 different applications sharing part of the code using the following gradle configuration:

```
flavorDimensions "Applications"

productFlavors {
    Application1{
        dimension "Applications"
        applicationId "com.example.app1"
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
    }
    Application2 {
        dimension "Applications"
        applicationId "com.example.app2"
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
    }
}
```

Comment: As far as I know, this will only add `:your_module_name` as dependency in my main module. What is more important, `:your_module_name` is still a library module, so it will compile to AAR instead of APK. This is not solution to my problem, because I want to be able to compile `:your_module_name` as part of main module but also as standalone APK.

Comment: I edited the the answer... I'm not quite sure if this can help you though

Comment: I've also edited my question to provide more specific example. I've considered using flavours but each flavour has to be added manually to build.gradle, which is menial work.

Comment: Did you check this: https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/gradle/getting-started-with-gradle-creating-a-multi-project-build/